# Project architecture with CocoaPods - Private main-project and public sub-project

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods, subproject

For my needs I am developing a private main-project which integrates a public sub-project that I've maid.

Currently, I have three git repositories:

- One private repository with the main-project.
- One public repository with the sub-project.
- One public repository with the .Podspec file to access to my sub-project using CocoaPods.

The problem is, when I work on the main-project and the sub-project in the same time, I have to:

- Work on the sub-project
- Push the modifications on its GitHub repository
- In the main-project directory run `pod install`

Moreover, I need to have two instance of xCode opened. One with the main-project and the other one with the sub-project. It's really unpleasant and unproductive to have to switch between xCode instances and push sub-project changes on its GitHub repository and using CocoaPods to get the sub-project modifications into the main-project.

I would like to work on the private project and the public project on the same repository.

A solution consists to put the main-project and the sub-project into the same repository.

But in the .podspec file I should set the URL of the main-project and finally turning the main project in public to let user access it. But I only to keep my main-project private.

So, is there any solution to work on the private main-project and the public sub-project in the same repository ?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Problem solved, http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2014/03/11/cocoapods-working-with-internal-pods/